# view XSLT source firefox?

Tags: firefox, xslt, firefox-developer-tools

I've been playing around with firefox but haven't found a way to view the XSLT source. If I go to "view source" then it only shows the XML source, and if I go to inspector it only shows the result of the transform. Is there a way to view the XSLT source?

Comment: The XSLT transformation is an XML file, too. If you transform XML with the browser, there is usually a processing instruction at the beginning that tells you which file contains the XSLT code. Open this file with the browser to look at the XSLT source.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Oh, I  didn't explain the problem well enough, it seems. I know the XSLT code; I've written it myself! What I want is to see that firefox has downloaded it and not cached an old version, and also to see how it parses it with warnings and error messages. It would be progress if I could open the XML source and click on the xml-stylesheet link to get at the downloaded XSLT file, but firefox doesn't allow this. I would like a list of all the secondary files that have been downloaded based on the XML file and have the opportunity to click on them to view the source.

Comment: @Henrik, i don't think firefox allows you to do that. it's just that XSLT in the browser never caught on as much as initially hoped/expected, to the functionality in browsers often is limited. what i'd recommend is to use firebug (or some other general browser debugging tool), which will allow you to better understand how the browser handles _all_ web resources, including XSLT.

Comment: @dret Thanks for the info and advice. Yes I know that XSLT never caught on (how foolish people are!) and that the project was left in limbo, but to view a source file seems like a very modest demand.

Answer (score 1):

In the XML source, at the start of the file, there will be a line such as this (formally referred to as an *XML Processing Instruction*):

`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="..."?>`

This line instructs the browser (in fact, any client interested in transforming the XML) where to find the XSLT. If you follow the link given in the `href` "attribute" (it's not in fact an actual XML attribute, but let's leave this aside for now), then you will find the XSLT source. This is exactly what your browser does, and you can do the same and then you can view the XSLT in the browser, or do whatever else you'd like to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect any element in the document you view (right click-> inspect element), open the network tab in the developer tools (you might need to reload to see requests), then you see the requested resources, right click the request for your XSLT stylesheet, you can then open it (open in new tab) and view its source. So I think it is possible, although it is a bit complicated.

Comment: Yes, it worked :) Thanks. Now I only need somebody to suggest a shortcut to get there, because there was a lot to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how, thanks to Martin above:

1. Ctrl shift Q goes straight to the network in the inspector.
2. Click reload.
3. You will now get a list of all the files loaded under the present doc.
4. Click once on the XSLT doc.
5. Click once on the response tab to the right.

And there you are :)